# MVC Call new Action and View from Javascript and send Array

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-5, window.location

I currently have an IEnumerable view in a grid which I have added check boxes, to allow me to select items (which I grab the id's via JavaScript and build an array of just the id's).

I have a button which should send the array to a new action and load the corresponding view.

I attempted at first to send the array via a JSON object which worked, but I could not get the controller to load a new view, it just returns the results to the current view (not what I am wanting).

So I am now just trying the following :

```
window.location.href = '/TeamSelector/TeamList?array=' +SwimmerList;
```

This is working but the object is not being sent correctly as I receive nothing in the array at the controller end.

```
    public ActionResult TeamList (List<int> Array)
    {
    // Do something here
    return view(results)
    }
```

Could somebody please advise me on how to structure the JavaScript code to send the array so that it will be accepted by the controller.

Any suggestion/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Andy.

Comment: It would need to be `/TeamSelector/TeamList?array=1&array=2&array=3` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you very much for the quick answer. I have just tested and it worked first time. I am going to write a little bit of code to iterate through the array and add the text to the url (this may take me 3 weeks and 4 more SO questions). Stephen could you post as the answer please so I can mark it, another question you have resolved for me and it is very appreciated.

Comment: If you give me 30 min, I'll also show you how to generate it with the values from the javascript array :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, no please don't I will figure it out and your time is much better spent helping the likes of me out when we get totally stuck !! I have the basics in my mind should not take me too long :)

Comment: OK done, but I'll update it later anyway :)

Comment: See update for one solution to building the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to post back a collection of values to a GET method with the signature

```
public ActionResult TeamList (List<int> Array)
```

your url needs to be

```
/TeamSelector/TeamList?array=1&array=2&array=3 // etc
```

One way to achieve this would be (assumes your checkboxes have `class="checkbox"`)

```
location.href = '/TeamSelector/TeamList?array=' + $('.checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join('&array=');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have persisted down the route of using Grid.MVC which I have found with time is very limiting and a pretty dead plugin. The checkbox functionality within this is strange and shows two check boxes and I can not seem to update them, so I add the click function to manually build up my array. Your elegant solution would be perfect with out Grid MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stephen and his answer, I have written a basic script to build the url with array data and all is working now.

```
        var url = '/TeamSelector/TeamList?';
    for (var i = 0; i < SwimmerList.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            url = url + 'array=' + SwimmerList[i];
        } else {
            url = url + '&array=' + SwimmerList[i];
        }
    }
    window.location.href = url;
```

Due to my using [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) I have struggled with the checkbox and getting the status of them so I ended up adding an on click to the checkbox and I control it that way to build my array up.